# Sending multiple files in java callback?

Tags: java, file, sockets, callback, server

How can I add to the sending queue, for example I choose a file with JFileChooser and then send it in a new thread to the client, and I want to choose another and send it as well. What happens is that it sends the files simultaneously and the output on the client side is broken.

I'd like to be able to add to a "queue" of some sort, so that when the first file is sent, the server will start sending the next one.

Comment: You need a communications protocol, like `FTP`

Comment: I have my own protocol included. It doesn't change a thing, because when the client starts to read bytes of the first file, and the server sends two files simultaneously, it will write to the file both of the incoming bytes. They have to be sent one after another in order to be recognized and downloaded properly.

My protocol in short is command$ and then if the command is file in this case, there's name$length$bytes

And after getting the command there is a switch and it runs a function for example for getting files. So I can't recognize then if another one is being sent

Comment: Why don't you create a zip of all files you want to send and send that zip?

Comment: you should follow your own advice and use a `Queue` (ArrayList should be fine, but you should `synchronize` either it or the accessors to it) You should only have 1 thread writing to your client... That thread should be reading data as in comes in on your queue. All your other threads should be posting jobs to the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good aproach for `socket communication` between server->client, is to have 1 thread per client and have this thread reading from a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`. Such interface is ideal (just like all the *java.util.concurrent* objects) for managing multithreading concurrency.

The idea, is that the Server has a `ClientThread` like this:

```
class BroadCastThread extends Thread{
    LinkedBlockingQueue<SendFileTask> bcQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while( true ){
            try {
                SendFileTask task = bcQueue.take();
                task.sendFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    void addTask(SendFileTask rt) throws InterruptedException{
        bcQueue.put(rt);
    }
}
interface SendFileTask{
    void sendFile() throws Exception;
}
```

And use this by `adding tasks` to you thread object:

```
        BroadCastThread bct = new BroadCastThread();
        bct.start();

        //With lambda
        bct.addTask(() -> {
            //Send file code
        });

        //Without lambda
        bct.addTask(new SendFileTask() {
            @Override
            void sendFile() throws Exception {
            //Send file code
            }
        });
```

You can even store the Socket information with the thread, and pass it throw the task interface, if you want the `sendFile` method to receive it as parameter.

Comment: So in such a way I only need to add tasks and they will be completed the order they were given?

Comment: Exactly. With all the thread concurrency handled automaticaly. And when the queue is empty, the client thread will be blocked at the 'bcQueue.take()' until there is a Task avaliable.